# How to find a specific tr row using jquery?

Tags: jquery

The HTML code may look like this...

```
              <tr data-mainrow>
                 <td class='column1'>This is col1</td>
                 <td class='checkbox'>Test</td>
              </tr>
              <tr data-mainrow>
                 <td class='column1'>This is col1</td>
                 <td class='checkbox'>Test</td>
              </tr>
need this---> <tr data-mainrow>
                 <td class='column1'>This is col1</td>
                 <td class='checkbox'>Test</td>
              </tr>
start here--> <tr></td><td class='checkbox'>Test</td></tr>
```

My goal is to select the first `tr[data-mainrow]` above the child of `td` with a class of `checkbox`...

```
$(".checkbox").closest(tr[data-mainrow]).find(".column1").text(); // should output This is col1 but not working
```

Comment: what is the event you are using this code?

Comment: I'm using the click event

Comment: Please update the question with full code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to traverse from the instance of the checkbox using `this` as a starting point in the event handler.

Example:

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(){  
     /* "this" is the element the event is firing on*/  
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var columntext = $row.find('.column1').text();
    alert(columnText);

});
```

I've used `closest()` assuming that you may actually use an input inside the `td` so it will work regardless of nesting

Answer (score 0):

this will do.

```
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
     var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
});
```